# jquery selectors - issue in chrome and ie

Tags: jquery

I am trying to execute a function when the .icon-menu is clicked but am having issues in chrome and IE where the function is not being activated.  Works fine in Firefox.  I have tried many variations but no luck.

```
    <a href="#" class="icon"><span class="icon-menu"></span></a> 

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a .icon-menu').click(function(){
       alert('yeah');
});
```

Can anyone assist?

Comment: May be the missing `});` is causing the issue. but since you said it works in FF, it should be the `document.ready`.

Comment: it is in document.ready and does have }),.  Id just copied it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to finish your syntax

```
$('a .icon-menu').click(function(){
   alert('yeah');
}); //   <-- notice the parenthesis and semi colon
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a .icon-menu').on('click',function(){
        alert(' yeah ');
    });
});
```